# Picamera http stream overlay static image

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, picamera

For a project, i would like overlay a static image (image of a circle - png) over a picamera http web stream (mjpeg).

Unfortunately picamera doesnt support overlays with recordings. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Here is the example code from the Picamera documentation:
https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes2.html#web-streaming

```
import io
import picamera
import logging
import socketserver
from threading import Condition
from http import server

PAGE="""\
<html>
<head>
<title>picamera MJPEG streaming demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>PiCamera MJPEG Streaming Demo</h1>
<img src="stream.mjpg" width="640" height="480" />
</body>
</html>
"""

class StreamingOutput(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = None
        self.buffer = io.BytesIO()
        self.condition = Condition()

    def write(self, buf):
        if buf.startswith(b'\xff\xd8'):
            # New frame, copy the existing buffer's content and notify all
            # clients it's available
            self.buffer.truncate()
            with self.condition:
                self.frame = self.buffer.getvalue()
                self.condition.notify_all()
            self.buffer.seek(0)
        return self.buffer.write(buf)

class StreamingHandler(server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.send_response(301)
            self.send_header('Location', '/index.html')
            self.end_headers()
        elif self.path == '/index.html':
            content = PAGE.encode('utf-8')
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            self.send_header('Content-Length', len(content))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(content)
        elif self.path == '/stream.mjpg':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Age', 0)
            self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private')
            self.send_header('Pragma', 'no-cache')
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=FRAME')
            self.end_headers()
            try:
                while True:
                    with output.condition:
                        output.condition.wait()
                        frame = output.frame
                    self.wfile.write(b'--FRAME\r\n')
                    self.send_header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
                    self.send_header('Content-Length', len(frame))
                    self.end_headers()
                    self.wfile.write(frame)
                    self.wfile.write(b'\r\n')
            except Exception as e:
                logging.warning(
                    'Removed streaming client %s: %s',
                    self.client_address, str(e))
        else:
            self.send_error(404)
            self.end_headers()

class StreamingServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, server.HTTPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True
    daemon_threads = True

with picamera.PiCamera(resolution='640x480', framerate=24) as camera:
    output = StreamingOutput()
    camera.start_recording(output, format='mjpeg')
    try:
        address = ('192.168.4.1', 8000)
        server = StreamingServer(address, StreamingHandler)
        server.serve_forever()
    finally:
        camera.stop_recording()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my initial attempt at this. I have put in comments above the lines I have added/changed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import io
import picamera
import logging
import socketserver
from threading import Condition
from http import server
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

PAGE="""\
<html>
<head>
<title>picamera MJPEG streaming demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>PiCamera MJPEG Streaming Demo</h1>
<img src="stream.mjpg" width="640" height="480" />
</body>
</html>
"""

class StreamingOutput(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = None
        # Open the overlay at startup and retain for pasting into all frames
        # Overlay MUST be "RGBA" mode
        self.overlay = Image.open('overlay.png')
        print(self.overlay)
        self.condition = Condition()

    def write(self, buf):
        # New frame, paste on our overlay and tell clients it's available
        with self.condition:
            # Convert the 640x480 buffer we receive into a PIL Image
            im = Image.frombuffer('RGB',(640,480),buf,"raw",'RGB',0,1)
            # Paste on our overlay
            im.paste(self.overlay,None,self.overlay)
            # Create an "in-memory" JPEG
            tmp = io.BytesIO()
            im.save(tmp,format='jpeg')
            # Copy that to "self.frame" for the HTTP server to send to clients
            self.frame = tmp.getvalue()
            self.condition.notify_all()
        return

class StreamingHandler(server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.send_response(301)
            self.send_header('Location', '/index.html')
            self.end_headers()
        elif self.path == '/index.html':
            content = PAGE.encode('utf-8')
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            self.send_header('Content-Length', len(content))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(content)
        elif self.path == '/stream.mjpg':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Age', 0)
            self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private')
            self.send_header('Pragma', 'no-cache')
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=FRAME')
            self.end_headers()
            try:
                while True:
                    with output.condition:
                        output.condition.wait()
                        frame = output.frame
                    self.wfile.write(b'--FRAME\r\n')
                    self.send_header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
                    self.send_header('Content-Length', len(frame))
                    self.end_headers()
                    self.wfile.write(frame)
                    self.wfile.write(b'\r\n')
            except Exception as e:
                logging.warning(
                    'Removed streaming client %s: %s',
                    self.client_address, str(e))
        else:
            self.send_error(404)
            self.end_headers()

class StreamingServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, server.HTTPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True
    daemon_threads = True

with picamera.PiCamera(resolution='640x480',framerate=24) as camera:
    output = StreamingOutput()
    # Collect data as RGB rather than encoding to JPEG, decoding from JPEG to PIL to overlay and then re-encoding as JPEG
    camera.start_recording(output,format='rgb')
    try:
        address = ('192.168.0.104', 8000)
        server = StreamingServer(address, StreamingHandler)
        server.serve_forever()
    finally:
        camera.stop_recording()
```

I tested it and it overlays fine. I created my overlay - which is a red circle in the middle of the screen - like this with **ImageMagick**:

```
convert -size 640x480 xc:lime -fill none +antialias -stroke red -fill none  -draw "circle 320,240 320,260" -transparent lime -depth 8 png32:overlay.png
```

Here it is overlaid onto the Raspberry Pi camera feed:

[image]

Comment: Works very well. Thank you!

Comment: Good! It's probably a good idea to make the overlay as small as possible for best performance and change the `None` in the line `im.paste()` accordingly. Good luck with your project! And come back if you get stuck.... questions (and answers) are free!